# How to make matrix like forms in Django

Tags: django, forms

I want to make a matrix like data entry form in my Django app.

Let's say the following are my models

```
class Student(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Subject(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Mark(models.Model):
    student = models.ForeignKey(Student, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    subject = models.ForeignKey(Subject, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    mark = models.DecimalField(max_digits=4, decimal_places=1)
```

Now I need to make a data entry form for Marks table in which all Student names to be prepopulated in rows (in the first column) and all Subjects to be prepopulated in columns (in the first row).

Then the user should be able to update the marks of each student for each subject in the form table.

The form should look something like this image.
https://cloud.addictivetips.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/03/datasheet2.jpg

How can this be made using Django?

Comment: Take a look at formsets https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/forms/formsets/

Comment: Thanks Henry. But I couldn't see anything about matrix like forms in formset documentation.

Comment: You'll have to create it using formsets.  There is nothing out of the box